# Button unclickable the second time

Tags: jquery, html

I got a problem with my jQuery code, when I press the 'edit' button, and then the 'cancel' button, if I then press 'edit' again, it won't work.

HTML

```
<div id="2">
<button class="edit" id="2">edit</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var post = $('div#'+id);
        var title = $('div#'+id+'>h1').html();
        var content = $('div#'+id+'>p').html();
        var edit = '<input type="text" class="title" id="'+id+'" value="title"><br>';
        var edit2 = '<textarea class="content" id="'+id+'" rows="10" cols="100">content</textarea>';
        $(this).remove();        
        post.append(edit);
        post.append(edit2);
        post.append('<br><button id="'+id+'" class="save">save</button><button id="'+id+'" class="cancel">cancel</button>');
        $('.cancel').click(function(){
            $('div#'+id+'>input').empty().remove();
            $('div#'+id+'>textarea').empty().remove();
            $(this).empty().remove();
            $('.save').empty().remove();
            $('div#'+id+'>br').remove();
            post.append('<button class="edit" id="'+id+'">Edit</button>');
        });
        /*$('.save').click(function(){
            var newTitle = $('input#'+id+'.title').val();
            var newContent = $('textarea#'+id+'.content').val();
            console.log(newTitle);
            console.log(newContent);
            console.log(id);
            $.post('/editPost', {id: id, title: newTitle, content: newContent}, function(){
                location.reload();
            });
        });*/
    });
```

jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/pHCT8/2/

Comment: use `on` or `live` event instead of `click`

Comment: When you do this: `$(this).remove();`, you remove the event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you CANNOT use same ID on two elements, this will surely render browser and JS errors.

(Also if youre not using HTML5 DOCTYPE then you shouldn't have ID's starting with a number)

Then use jQuery `on()` syntax as a live handler:

```
$('#2').on('click','.edit', function(){
```

Note that the starting `$('#2')` is the outer limit of where you want the click listener to work. If you need it wide then use `$('body').on('click','.edit', function(){` this will listen to all `.edit` clicks inside the whole body tag

Reason is that your click event handler only work upon elements loaded with the DOM, but your ajax edit function will create elements that wasn't in the DOM when loaded (dynamically created).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than actually getting rid of the button, why not just .hide on click, then .show when you click cancel?

http://jsfiddle.net/pHCT8/5/

The changed portions are:

`$(this).hide();` rather than `$(this).remove;`

`$('.edit').show();` rather than `post.append('<button class="edit" id="'+id+'">Edit</button>');`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destroying and recreating the button(in which case you lose the event handlers) you can hide/show it

```
var self = $(this).hide();
...
$('.cancel').click(function(){
    ...
    self.show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/pHCT8/4/